# Why does this string function not update? MQL4

Tags: mql4, trading, algorithmic-trading, forex, mt4

I'm super confused right now, been at this for some time. I'm trying to figure out why this string function won't update the string when I believe the if statement to be true.

```
void OnTick()
{
     string aboveprofit = "";

     for ( int b = OrdersTotal() - 1; b >= 0; b-- )
     {
          if ( OrderSelect( b, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_TRADES ) )
          if ( OrderSymbol() == Symbol() )
          {
               if ( OrderSymbol() == OP_SELL )
               {
                    OrderModify( OrderTicket(),
                                 OrderOpenPrice(),
                                 Bid + ( 150 * _Point ),
                                 OrderTakeProfit(),
                                 0,
                                 CLR_NONE
                                 );
                    if ( Ask < OrderOpenPrice() )
                    {    
                         abovepoint = "321";
                    }
               }
               if ( OrderSymbol() == OP_BUY )
               {
                    OrderModify( OrderTicket(),
                                 OrderOpenPrice(),
                                 Ask - ( 150 * _Point ),
                                 OrderTakeProfit(),
                                 0,
                                 CLR_NONE
                                 );
                    if ( Bid > OrderOpenPrice() )
                    {
                         abovepoint = "123";
                    }
               }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Q** : *"why this string function won't update the string when I believe the if statement to be true?"*

Well, how do you know it did not?

Add a `Print( Volume[0], abovepoint );` command right onto the first line right upon the entry to the `void OnTick(){...}`-code-block, so as to check the validity of your above posted assumption in the Client Terminal log.

The code fragment above is missing an actual `abovepoint` declaration, so it is impossible to add anything more than this.

---

ERRATA : **`OrderSymbol()`** will most probably never match **`{ OP_BUY | OP_SELL }`**-constants, it ought be `OrderType()`, ought be not?

The **`OrderModify()`**-commands are almost sure to generate server-side rejections of any XTO-instruction, that will violate either a Broker-side defined FREEZE_LEVEL and/or minimum permitted distances of modified `{ TP | SL }`-targets from the actual `{ Ask | Bid }`-price-levels. Kindly review your Broker's T&C and best adapt your code to prevent falling into those conditions colliding instructions.

Comment: I’m an idiot. I declared “aboveprofit” as a string but was trying to update a missed spelt “abovepoint” string.

By the way the OrderSymbol does match op_sell and op_buy because the OrderModify function works fine.

Comment: I doubt, it could --- **`OrderSymbol()`** - Returns symbol ***name*** of the currently selected order, whereas **`OrderType()`** - Returns order operation ***type*** of the currently selected order ~ **`{ OP_BUY | OP_BUYSTOP | OP_BUYLIMIT | OP_SELL | OP_SELLSTOP | OP_SELLLIMIT }`**